# Storing Functions inside of Types

Tags: function, types, julia

Usually one wants to define their types strict and while leaving loose type restrictions on methods (since the latter will automatically specialize, so there's no performance gain). Thus I know that for defining functions, using `::Base.Callable` is good practice. However, what about when storing functions inside of types?

In v0.5, `Function` and `Base.Callable` are both abstract types, and so the type

```
type TestType
  f::Base.Callable # or ::Function
end
```

will not be strictly typed. One could strictly type this by using

```
type TestType{T<:Base.Callable}
  f::T
end
```

which will then produce a different type for every function.

What are the benefits and drawbacks to the different approaches? It seems like the second method would cause any `g(t::TestType)` to recompile for every input function, while the first method will not have the `f` strictly typed. So would the second be better if you want to inline the functions (and these types are "pretty much constant"), and the first be better if you'll be changing the functions a lot? Or am I way overthinking this?

Comment: I personally would go even further and recommend `Any` instead of `Base.Callable`, to capture situations like `Polynomial`.

Comment: Yup, those are the tradeoffs.  Not sure there's an answer beyond that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally when I'm on the fence, I prefer the parameterized version because it's more general. It's simple to do `TestType{Any}` or `TestType{Function}` if you have parameterized types, and these types will behave exactly like the unparameterized `TestType`.

For instance, `Base` has `Vector{T}` which can be used for both specific cases like `Vector{Any}` and special cases like `Vector{Int}`, and in a similar vein you could have `TestType{T}` which could be useful for both `TestType{Any}` or `TestType{typeof(sin)}`.